# Protractor id of element dynamically generated

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I want to know that is possible to find element by partial id, because on page which I'm testing id is dynamic(The first part of the id has a variable number) and I can't know whole id.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it, e.g. with a CSS selector:

```
// starts-with
element(by.css("div[id^=test]"));

// ends-with
element(by.css("div[id$=test]"));

// contains
element(by.css("div[id*=test]"));
```

Or, with an XPath (no ends-with here):

```
// starts-with
element(by.xpath("//div[starts-with(@id, 'test')]"));

// contains
element(by.xpath("//div[contains(@id, 'test')]"));
```